# lldb arrow key issue

Tags: centos, clang, llvm, lldb

I'm building the llvm/clang/lldb tool chain on my CentOS 6.6.

I checked out the code of the version 3.7 and built the clang/lldb executable successfully. Everything works grateful except when I launch the `lldb` debugger and hit the `arrow keys` I just get:

```
$ lldb
(lldb) ^[[A                      <-- What I hit is the `up` key
(lldb) ^[[B                      <-- What I hit is the `down` key
```

Same issues on the `left` and `right` keys.

How can I get the `arrow keys` work in the `lldb` just as it should do, move the cursor and navigate the command history? Do I need any external configurations or do I need to rebuild the `lldb` with certain options?

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason. I should `not` disable the `libedit` by specify `-DLLDB_DISABLE_LIBEDIT=1`.

Comment: Yes, that flag is just there to support platforms that don't have libedit - mostly mobile OS'es.